# datagridview formatting working for one grid but not the other?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

So I have a function that applies formatting to the datagridviews I have in my form (currently 2 but plan on more) this formatting works on one datagrid but not the second one, however strangely SOME of the formatting is working, namely the sort and read-only properties.

This Works : -   https://gyazo.com/2f2d9718fe6d997d33fda2ac04a38c5f

This Doesn't : - https://gyazo.com/820ea3394af23af16faf22035883a799

This is the code

```
private void datagridformat(DataGridView datagrid)
{
    datagrid.Sort(datagrid.Columns["ID"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    datagrid.Columns["ID"].ReadOnly = true;
    datagrid.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in datagrid.Columns)
       column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;

}
```

This is called by the below methods (in brackets is the name of the datagrids)

```
 datagridformat(StandardsCheck);
 datagridformat(InstallCheck);
```

Now as stated above - the function works for the first datagrid (StandardsCheck) but not the second (InstallCheck) it does not matter which way round I call them E.G. The above (StandardsCheck) first has the same result as

```
 datagridformat(InstallCheck);
 datagridformat(StandardsCheck);
```

Again, the "NotSortable" and "ID, ListSortDirection" and "ReadOnly" works, however the AutoResizeColumns bit is not, and I cannot see why?

Edit : -

Just tested, `InstallCheck.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);` by itself, this does not work either. Perhaps a property is set in the properties however both grids are identical?

Any help is kindly received

Thank you

Comment: Check `AutoSizeColumnsMode` property of the grids.

Comment: Compare the settings in the Designer.cs file to see if all the setting are identical.